# Layer group export in KMZ format in geoserver

Tags: geoserver, layers, kmz

I have created a layer group in Geoserver with several layers, but while I am exporting the layer into kmz and viewing in google earth all the consisting layers are displaying in the side panel. is it possible to display only the layer group name instead of all the layer which inside the layer group.

Answer (score 2):

No, not possible, layer groups literally "do not exist" inside the OGC services of GeoServer, the moment the request comes in the group is split into the equivalent list of layers and disappears.